# Indexing document in ElasticSearch Id null failure

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm trying to index this document document into ES. I'm currently doing a **POST** for the document creation:

```
{  
   "name":"facility 3",
   "types":[  
      1
   ],
   "status":1,
   "registrationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "capacity":0,
   "rating":0.0,
   "licenseStatus":0,
   "licenseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "licenseCloseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "address":"10 thomas avenue*",
   "zipCode":"12345",
   "rentLow":0.0,
   "rentHigh":0.0,
   "basePriceLow":0.0,
   "basePriceHigh":0.0,
   "oneTimeFee":0.0,
   "levelOfCareRangeMinimum":0.0,
   "levelOfCareRangeMaximum":0.0,
   "city":"new york city",
   "state":"New York",
   "facilityManagements":[  
      {  
         "userId":"3e85f416-b00a-407e-a34e-05cec99f38b1",
         "operations":1,
         "isOwner":true,
         "isActive":true,
         "createdDate":"2018-06-29T16:08:19.7700068Z",
         "id":"d7db8c5b-24a2-4a5f-a508-1188233b305f"
      }
   ],
   "facilityRequests":[  
      {  
         "userId":"3e85f416-b00a-407e-a34e-05cec99f38b1",
         "createdDate":"2018-06-29T16:08:19.7709542Z",
         "status":1,
         "id":"77cfa81e-0f62-47ff-8956-b15b7c4321f0"
      }
   ],
   "slug":"facility-3-10-thomas-avenue",
   "approved":false,
   "businessLocation":{  
      "lat":40.7143545,
      "lon":-74.0059735
   },
   "serviceAreas":{  
      "coordinates":[  
         [  
            [  
               0.0,
               0.0
            ]
         ]
      ],
      "type":"polygon"
   },
   "suggest":{  
      "input":[  
         "new york city",
         "New York",
         "facility",
         "3"
      ]
   }
}
```

However, this is resulting in the following error `id must not be null`. I do not get it because, I thought ES would generate the ID in this case. Also, I've index my mapping using NEST:

```
  var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearch-Node1"]);
            var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(uri);
            //ElasticSearch Client
            string index = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticIndex"];
            return new ConnectionSettings(pool).DefaultIndex(index)
                .DefaultMappingFor<Facility>(m => m.IndexName(index).TypeName("doc"));
```

Facility has a bunch of other inner nested objects that is being indexed with it.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to index the document?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've some sort of error with your index mapping because when I try with your data to index it on my local elasticsearch without any predefined scheme it just works as expected and it auto generated the 20 character long, URL-safe, Base64-encoded GUID strings ID. See my working snap

[image]

**Autogenerating IDs**

> If our data doesn’t have a natural ID, we can let Elasticsearch
>   autogenerate one for us. The structure of the request changes: instead
>   of using the PUT verb (“store this document at this URL”), we use the
>   POST verb (“store this document under this URL”).

See more : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html#_autogenerating_ids